# release object's memory VS termination housekeeping?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I am studying a book called "C++ How to Program" by Paul Deitel, chapter 9 is talking about Classes, and I quote:

> *The destructor itself does **not** actually **release** the object's memory--it performs **termination housekeeping** before the object's
>   memory is reclaimed, so the memory may be reused to hold new objects.*

so my question is, what does the Author mean by Termination housekeeping and releasing memory? and how different they are from each other? if they are any different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it means is the destructor function does not release memory, but it is a place where you can declare what housekeeping functions need to be done. For example, if your object owns pointers to other data that it should release, then it's time to delete those. For example if you had a pointer named `owned` that was given something to retain:

```
MyThing::~MyThing() {
  delete owned;
}
```

This `delete` call will trigger the destructor for that `owned` object if it has one, which initiates this process all over again in a recursive manner.

You might also close file-handles, delete temporary files, whatever it is your object should do when tidying up. That might include deleting operating-system GUI elements as well, it really depends on where this code lives.

The destructor is called during the process of releasing memory, but it itself does not release any of its own memory. That action is performed after the destructor finishes.

Answer (score 1):

There are other forms of cleanup besides releasing memory.  Sometimes you may need to close a communications channel during the terminator of a class.  Or you might release resources used for threading when a class closes.  Or maybe you just modify a pointed to object.

The destructor is the code that runs when the object falls out of scope.  There's nothing else to it.